# Global module definition for typescript

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-typings, typescript-eslint

I'm working on a project in Webstorm with the following file structure

```
| src
    | ...
    | many files
| types
    | SomeInterface
        | index.d.ts
    | AnotherInterface
        | index.d.ts
    | index.d.ts
```

I would like to make `SomeInterface` globally available (use the Interface without the need of an import).

My main `index.d.ts` is the following:

```
import { SomeInterface } from './SomeInterface'
import { AnotherInterface} from './AnotherInterface'

declare global {
  interface MainInterface extends SomeInterface {
    someAttribute?: number[]
    names: SomeInterface[]
    contactData: AnotherInterface[]
  }
}
```

Whenever I try to implement type definition in `src/some/path/to/file.ts`:

```
function someFunctionName(parsedData: MainInterface):void{...}
```

I get the following message:
`ESLint: 'MainInterface' is not defined.(no-undef)`

This is my current tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src", "types/index.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Am I missing something? I'm aware that making things globally available isn't recommended, however I was asked to to it in this way specifically.

Comment: So this question is about using ES Lint with TypeScript?

Comment: @AluanHaddad At first i wasnt sure if it was a type defintion issue or a linter issue. Based on Brad's answer it looks like it's a ESLint/TsLint issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you define custom globals in your code, you need to tell ESLint about them: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals

Though, I would just consider turning off the `no-undef` rule though, as it's a check that's already covered by TypeScript itself.

Answer (score 10):

The [typescript-eslint FAQ](https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting/#i-get-errors-from-the-no-undef-rule-about-global-variables-not-being-defined-even-though-there-are-no-typescript-errors) provides guidance here:

> We strongly recommend that you do not use the no-undef lint rule on
> TypeScript projects. The checks it provides are already provided by
> TypeScript without the need for configuration - TypeScript just does
> this significantly better.

But `no-undef` is useful for JavaScript, so if you have mixed usage it's better to disable it only for files that are using TypeScript e.g. for Vue + TypeScript:

```
"overrides": [
    {
        "files": ["*.ts", "*.vue"],
        "rules": {
            "no-undef": "off"
        }
    }
]
```

Of course don't then write Vue files using JavaScript since `no-undef` is disabled.